# Sending notifications between devices using Firebase SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send upstream messages from a device using the Firebase JavaScript SDK?

For example, would it be possible to send a push notification to another device without the use of an external server?

Comment: So it's basically sending from one device (*client app*) directly to another device?

Comment: @AL. Think in terms of a messaging app, when a user sends a message is it possible to notifiy the recipient via push without the use of an external server?